Using Shiny to combine and display copy and pasted data
I am trying to create a very basic web app that allows a user to copy and paste Excel tables and display them on the app. I would normally use data <- read.delim('clipboard'), then paste(data) if I was using an R script. If I run:
ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("file", "Select a file"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderText({
    filePath <- input$file$datapath
    fileText <- paste(readLines(filePath), collapse = "\n")
    fileText
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

It allows a user to upload a csv file to display, but how would I incorporate a 'copy and paste' method of data import? Any advice?

rhandsontable allows you to copy & paste. Check it out here: https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable or here: https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/

Try this option using the clipr package. You can read a table from your clipboard.
How to use:

Copy the table in excel
Click the copy button in the App

library(clipr)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("read_clip", "Read from clipboard"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  table <- eventReactive(input$read_clip, {
    read_clip_tbl()
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    req(table())
    table()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

